# Make a job easily searchable in Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I have a number of different jobs in my Azure Runbook. However, I don't have an easy way of differentiating between jobs when I look at the Overview of the Runbook. I am forced to click on each individual job to see which one it is. Is there a way I can "label" my job so that it is easily identifiable from the Overview screen?

Thanks!

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask. SO is mainly for coding questions

Comment: Thanks! Just posted.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK currently there is no way to label job so that it is easily identifiable from the Overview screen. If interested, you may raise feature request in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation) UserVoice / feedback forum. I see [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/10360965-ui-improvements) related feature request already raised so you may even upvote it. In general, Azure feature team would check feasibility of a feature request, triage it, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.